# Need tips to build a database of securities

Tags: database

I'm going to build an enterprise grade database on the topic of securities. I read on the SEC website that there is an CIK code the government uses. I suppose there are also other identifiers. Anyone done this recently? Can you please point me out to where I can download lists of securities and their identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a list if all companies. I believe this is what you want, from the SEC Edgar database

http://www.sec.gov/edgar/indices/fullindex.htm

Comment: This is a great start. Since I posted my question I also read about CUSIP ID's- is there a free source for CUSIP ID's?

Comment: Oh, and by the way the link you provided also led me to ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/, which looks great

Comment: It looks like the CUSIP database is managed by the American Bankers Association. There is a special website for their data products https://www.cusip.com/cusip/index.htm

Comment: On their website it says ABA wants $45k for a license -  I wrote to them to find out if they have any cheaper options.